# using count as index of string how to generate random words?

Tags: java, text-files, counter

I am writing a hangman program and I wanted to take word text file was working fine being able to populate an array list and generate a random word from the array-list. but i want to do something new. what the program is doing is fairly easy and straight forward it is reading a text file line by line and each time its reading a line it increments the count. but I want to generate a random word from that text file using the count value as index of a word in the text file. Can anyone please help me out with where can I get documentation about this problem?

```
public class WordReader {


    private static String fileName = "Wordlist.txt";
    int count = 0;

    public WordReader() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file))){
            int count=0;
            while(sc.hasNext()){
                sc.next();
                count++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to get a random position from within the text file? that way whenever you want a new word you have to open up and traverse the file. Much more efficient to load it into a structure and get the words as and when they are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] words = new string[<Size of array, for example lines count>]
```

Then add words line by line in "words" array

```
using (StreamReader a = new StreamReader("Words.txt")){
    words[i] = a.ReadLine();
}
```

now you need to get a random line

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int random = rnd.next(0,words.Count()-1)
string output = words[random];
```

Comment: thank you everyone for your input.
@Taha225 it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Load them into an array list of strings, so 1st initialise the array list

```
ArrayList<String> dict = new ArrayList()<>;
```

Then you need to add a line to the array List (assuming it's one word per line)

```
dict.add(sc.next);
```

then you need to get a random number of the length of the word, once all words have been added to a list

```
Random rand = new Random();
int choice = rand.nextInt(dict.size());
String wordChoice = dict.get(choice);
```